# Вывод определенных столбцов из csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Есть сsv файл с именованными колонками вида:

```
id;name;address;zip
1;vasya;moscow;11111
2;oleg;sochi;22222
```

Как мне **с помощью стандартного модуля csv** вывести только столбцы к примеру name и zip? В дальнейшем необходимо сформировать новый csv файл только с этими двумя колонками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил, может кому пригодится:

```
import csv

with open('f_name', 'r') as f:
    incl_col = [1, 3]                          # индексы нужных столбцов
    new_csv = []                              # новый список для нового файла
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        col = list(row[i] for i in incl_col)
        print(col)                            # вывод нужных столбцов
        new_csv.append(col)                   # заполняем новый список нужными столбцами

with open('new.csv', 'w') as f:               # создаем новый файл
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerows(new_csv)
```

Comment: Молодец, что сами разобрались :) Есть такое предложение: `col = list(row[i] for i in incl_col)` -> `col = [row[i] for i in incl_col]` -> `col = [row[i] for i in (1, 3)]` -> `col = row[1], row[3]`. Сами выберите на каком этапе остановиться :)

Comment: да, отличное дополнение

Answer (score 0):

я решил для себя эту проблему используя class csv.DictReader. С его помощью можно обращаться прямо по ключам словаря получая нужные данные. Вот код:

```
import csv
with open('f_name') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=";")

    for row in reader:
        print(row['name'], row['zip'])  # вывод столбцов по их именамde
```

Ну, а как это использовать решать только вам.
Вывод:

```
vasya 11111
oleg 22222
```